# Twisted script issue

Tags: python, twisted, twistd

I have written a Twisted `bin` file that is deployed on `/usr/bin` during application deployement, based on the `Axiom` example provided elsewhere on StackOverflow (I don't remember where), the project can be [found here](https://github.com/twisted/axiom/blob/master/twisted/plugins/axiom_plugins.py).

My problem is that, during the `python setup.py install` process, the installed bin file is different than the one from Axiom package:

**/usr/bin/axiomatic**

```
#!/code/venv/bin/python
from axiom.scripts import axiomatic
axiomatic.main()
```

**/usr/bin/myapp**

```
#!/code/venv/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-DEV-SCRIPT: 'MyApp==0.0.1','myapp'
__requires__ = 'MyApp==0.0.1'
__import__('pkg_resources').require('MyApp==0.0.1')
exec(compile(open(__file__).read(), __file__, 'exec'))
```

and the latter doesn't work when invoking it from the bash shell: `myapp start`

I get the following error: `unknow command myapp`

If I use `python setup.py develop` instead of `python setup.py install` everything works smoothly.

---

I have setup a little test application that starts a tcp service on port 1234:

- the command `twistd finger` **works**, the service starts
- the command `fingerize start` (different name on purpose, to be sure not calling the wrong one) **doesn't work**

Here is the code:

**bin/fingerize**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from finger import tap
tap.main()
```

**twisted/plugins/finger_plugin.py**

```
from twisted.application.service import ServiceMaker
Finger = ServiceMaker('Finger', 'finger.plugins', 'blah', 'finger')
```

**finger/plugins.py**

```
from twisted.application import internet
from twisted.internet import endpoints
from twisted.python import usage
from twisted.internet import protocol


class Options(usage.Options):
    """ """


def makeService(options):
    from twisted.internet import reactor

    endpoint = endpoints.TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 1234)
    return internet.StreamServerEndpointService(
        endpoint,
        protocol.Factory())
```

**finger/tap.py**

```
import sys

from twisted.python import usage
from twisted.scripts import twistd


class Start(twistd.ServerOptions):
    run = staticmethod(twistd.run)

    def subCommands(self):
        raise AttributeError()

    subCommands = property(subCommands)

    def parseOptions(self, args):
        print(sys.argv)
        print(args)
        a = self.getArguments(args)
        print(a)
        sys.argv[1:] = a
        print(sys.argv)
        print('Starting finger service...')
        self.run()

    def getArguments(self, args):
        args.extend(['--pidfile', self.parent.pid()])
        args.extend(['finger'])
        return args


class Options(usage.Options):
    def subCommands():
        def get(self):
            yield ('start', None, Start, 'Launch finger service')

        return get,

    subCommands = property(*subCommands())

    def pid(self):
        return '/tmp/finger.pid'


def main(argv=None):
    o = Options()
    try:
        o.parseOptions(argv)
    except usage.UsageError, e:
        raise SystemExit(str(e))
```

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

METADATA = dict(
    name='Finger',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    scripts=['bin/fingerize'],
    install_requires=[
        'Twisted >= 15.5.0',
    ],
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
)

setup(**METADATA)
```

And when I call `fingerize start` I get: `/code/test/bin/fingerize: Unknown command: finger` (test is a virtualenv)

Comment: The issue is with your `setup.py` which you have not included.

Comment: oups sorry, I add it now, it is deeply inspired from `Twisted` one

Comment: The `txmyapp.python.dist` is irrelevant, the `verifyInstall()` function just checks for folders and `raise IOError` if not found.

Comment: my setup `dict` and the axiom `dict` are almost the same, but the `bin/cmd` is different, see my edits on top of the post

Comment: It's not irrelevant.  Please attach an http://sscce.org so I can run your entire example.

Comment: I have updated with a simple sscee, I just miss the `setup.py` but I don't have it with me, I'll post it as soon as I can.

Comment: I have added the setup.py, the example should now be working.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using setuptools in your `setup.py`, you can use the newer `entry_points` keyword, like so:

`entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'fingerize=finger.tap:main',
    ],
},`

instead of the `scripts` keyword.

Note if `python setup.py install` is run in a virtualenv, it will put the script in `env/bin/fingerize` (assuming your virtualenv folder is `env`).

A nice way to make such "python applications" then available globally (for some deployment purpose), while their inner mechanics doesn't interfere with your system python applciations, is to use [pipsi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pipsi) (`pip install pipsi`) (made by the guy who developed flask). It's designed to expose just the project's executables to the system and have everything else tucked away in its own virtualenv.

You can see more on how to write/configure/distribute python packages at the [packaging.python.org](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/) guide.

Comment: I have tried to use both `scripts` and `entry_points` but I still get the same error. I am aware of the virtualenv scripts dir.

Comment: could you try `/code/test/bin/fingerize` and `fingerize`? They could be different.

Comment: I have tested right now and I have the exact same issue. If you run the script as provided does it works for you?

Comment: Found it. `find_packages()` won't work without an `__init__.py`. run `touch finger/__init__.py` and you should be golden. Alternatively on Python 3, you could use `packages=['finger']`.

Comment: This does not work either, I still have the `__init__.py` in my finger module dir. If the code works for you, can you send me a full [ssccee](http://sscce.org/) example to test ? Maybe I am missing something really basic/stupid. (Also to be sure, are you running `fingerize start` ? because just typing `fingerize` works, it is the subCommand that is not working)

Comment: @kitensei, all I did was literally copy paste all of your files into a new virtualenv, implement my change suggested above, add a `__init__.py`, run `python setup.py install`, and the `fingerize` command ran without error.
I have not looked at whether the actual functional logic of your code works, because that was not really what the question seemed to be about.

Comment: you ran the `fingerize start` ? If you did, I may have another problem linked to my python install maybe...

Comment: *just thinking about it, could it be a python 2.7.5 issue* ?